# Using axios in Vue but data is not loading asynchronously

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I'm using Laravel with Vue as a front-end framework, and for ajax calls I'm using axios, but data is loading only when the page is refreshed.

Routes:

Route::get('/comment','CommentController@show');
 Route::post('/store','CommentController@store');

Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>

    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>title</label>
            <input v-model="comment.title" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>body</label>
          <textarea v-model="comment.body" class="form-control" placeholder="Add comment.."></textarea>
      </div>
      <button @click.prevent="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
   </form>

   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            comment:{
                title:"",
                body:""
            }
       }
   },
    methods:{
        add: function(){
            axios.post('/store',{
                title: this.comment.title,
                body: this.comment.body
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);   
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
           });
       }
  }
}
</script>
```

CommentController:

```
public function show(){
    $comments= comment::orderby('id','desc')->get();
    return $comments;
}

public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=> 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    comment::create([
        'title'=> request('title'),
        'body' => request('body')
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: The POST is only going through after you hit refresh?

Comment: Yes, It's confusing when I'm using ajax why it's not loading async.

Comment: What happens if you take out the .prevent from the button?

Comment: Nothing, it gives the same result.